# Best indexing strategy for time series in a mysql database with timestamps

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, time-series

I have a database that I'm taking care of containing pulse measurements.
The schema is like this:

```
id - monitorid - starttime - stoptime - pulses
```

Every monitor gives information every 10 minutes.
Currently that adds up to about 13 000 000 rows.

The start- and stoptime are varchar(10)'s, holding unix timestamps. Probably not the most efficiënt for my case.

Almost all queries against this table are 'WHERE starttime > $certaintime AND monitorid = $monid'. All these queries are currently extremely slowly.

I have an index on monitorid. I haven't yet put any on starttime and stoptime, since I figured that that will hardely give me any better cardinality, since each 10 minute slot is a new value. I'm not sure of this reasoning though.

So, my question: how would one optimize this for the range-like queries that it is confronted with mostly. Index starttime? Rebuild the table with dates instead of timestamps?

Any advice is most welcome!

Cheers,

Dieter

Comment: unix timestamps (integers) in a varchar column? Storing integers in a text-based column isn't the greatest idea.

Comment: Will that greatly impact performance? I suppose I'd make it far easier for MySQL if they are actually numbers, easier sorting and what not.

Comment: yes, especially if you're doing numerical comparisons. you'd be forcing mysql to do a string->int conversion anytime you had `where starttime > 123` type stuff. Of course, you could always cast that 123 to be a string, but string comparisons are still more expensive in cpu terms than an integer comparison. Plus wonky results like `99 > 100` being true in string land.

Comment: Thanks, that might be a great place to try for some performance improvement. I'll have to figure out how to do the replacing of the columns though. Cheers!

Comment: `alter table yourtable change starttime bigint default null` or whatever would do it. as long as ALL of the string values in there can be successfully converted to ints.

Comment: Thanks, going to try that out and see how my ORM reacts. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a compound btree index on `monitorid + starttime` columns.
This index can give the best results for queries which use `WHERE starttime > X AND monitorid = Y` clause

```
CREATE INDEX name ON tablename( monitorid + starttime )
```

`monitorid` must be a leading column in this index, otherwise the index will be not usable.
Read a chapter "8.2.1.3.2 The Range Access Method for Multiple-Part Indexes" for details here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html

They write that:

> For a BTREE index, an interval might be usable for conditions combined with AND, where each condition compares a key part with a constant value using =, <=>, IS NULL, >, <, >=, <=, !=, <>, BETWEEN, or LIKE 'pattern' (where 'pattern' does not start with a wildcard). An interval can be used as long as it is possible to determine a single key tuple containing all rows that match the condition (or two intervals if <> or != is used).
>
> The optimizer attempts to use additional key parts to determine the interval **as long as the comparison operator is =, <=>, or IS NULL. If the operator is >, <, >=, <=, !=, <>, BETWEEN, or LIKE, the optimizer uses it but considers no more key parts.** For the following expression, the optimizer uses = from the first comparison. It also uses >= from the second comparison but considers no further key parts and does not use the third comparison for interval construction:
>
> **key_part1** = 'foo' AND **key_part2** >= 10 AND **key_part3** > 10

(emphasis mine)
The above means, that in your specific case if an index on `monitorid + starttime` will be created, then the opimizec can use both part of the index because `monitorid = $monid` is used in the where clause, but in a case of reverse index order `starttime + monitorid`, the second part of the index is not usable because `starttime > $certaintime` is used in the where clause.

Comment: Haven't been able to try it out yet, but great answer and looks like sound advice. Thanks!